# how do i show latest 10 posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to show the latest 10 posts from all categories. How can i do it? Currently it shows post from featured category

```
<?php

            query_posts('category_name=featured&showposts=1');
            while(have_posts()):the_post();
            $attrs = array(
        'src'   => $src,
        'class' => "",
        'alt'   => get_the_title(),
        'title' => get_the_title(),
    );?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about reading the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)? this would suggest

```
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=10' );
```

this is for version 2.1 and up; for versions below you would use

```
query_posts( 'showposts=10' );
```